# Method containing closure parameter expects wrong type?

Tags: generics, rust, closures

I have a struct, `Parser` which contains a `transformer` - a function used to modify its `ParserState`- and the said `ParserState`.

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Parser<F> 
where
    F: Fn(ParserState) -> ParserState
{
    pub transformer: F,
    pub state: ParserState
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct ParserState {
    pub target: String,
    pub index: usize,
    pub result: Vec<String>, // the container of eventual results from the parsing, with Some(result) or None. Should be a vetor
    pub error: bool,            // whether we've encountered an error; index -> 0, Some(err_msg)
    pub err_msg: Option<String> // Eventual error message
}
```

Defining a `.map()` method, I assumed that I could simply use a closure, and reference the parser's own state within it as passing it as an argument to that closure. This closure would be used as a parameter of the `.map()` method.

```rust
impl<F> Parser<F>
where
    F: Fn(ParserState) -> ParserState 
{
    pub fn new(f: F) -> Self {
        // creating a new Parser just means deciding on which closure it applies
        Parser {
            transformer: f,
            state: ParserState {
                target: String::from(""),
                index: 0,
                result: vec![],
                error: false,
                err_msg: None
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn map<G>(&mut self, g: G) -> ()
    where
        G: Fn(ParserState) -> ParserState
    {
        self.state = g((self.state).clone())
    }

    pub fn run(mut self, corpus: String) -> Self {
        self.state.target = corpus;
        self.state = (self.transformer)(self.state);
        self
    }
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```
fn main() {
    let haystack: String = String::from("Hello!Goodbye!");
    let needle = String::from("Hello!");
    let str_parser = Parser::new(str_parser(needle));
    let closure = |mut state: ParserState| state.index = 0;
    let result = str_parser.run(haystack);
    let result = result.map(closure);
    let adv = ParserState {
        target: "Hello!Goodbye!".to_string(),
        index: 0,
        result: vec!["Hello!".to_string()],
        error: false,
        err_msg: None
    };
    assert_eq!(adv, result.state);
}
```

This has not worked. I have encountered this error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<[closure@src/lib.rs:49:23: 49:63] as std::ops::FnOnce<(parse
rs::ParserState,)>>::Output == parsers::ParserState`
  --> src/lib.rs:51:29
   |
51 |         let result = result.map(closure);
   |                             ^^^ expected `()`, found struct `parsers::ParserState`
```

and am not sure how `FnOnce`, which I have not mentioned, is relevant. I also do not understand how `.map()` expects `()` as an argument, when it is a method of the `Parser`. I feel a little bit out of my depth here.

Here is a link to [the relevant Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=025afdce9bcd7ca5433088e901aed490)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This closure returns `()` (i.e. it doesn't return a value):

```
let closure = |mut state: ParserState| state.index = 0;
```

But `F` is declared to return a `ParserState`. You just need to make the function return the value, as expected.

```
let closure = |mut state: ParserState| {
    state.index = 0;
    state
};
```

> and am not sure how `FnOnce`, which I have not mentioned, is relevant.

`FnOnce` is the most general function trait; all functions can be called at least once, so all functions implement `FnOnce`, but might not implement `Fn` or `FnMut`. I think the fact that it mentions `FnOnce` in the error message is just an artifact of the order in which it attempts to match the types.